# index of nth-child within the CSS rule?

Tags: html, css, indexing, css-selectors

Is there a CSS only approach to get the "child index" number the rule is applying at a certain point?

I want to do something like this

```
div:nth-child(1n+0) {
    transform: translate3d( calc(index-nth * 50), 0, 0);
}
```

is that even possible with plain CSS3? I know I could use SASS or LESS and iterate through a number of preset elements but I'd like it to not be hard-coded into the CSS but be there for any number of possible elements.

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: @MrLister I need to know the element i'm in to calculate a position for it, so, if I have 10 elements, I want the 1st one to be positioned at 1*50 and the 10th at 10*50

Comment: @Dunnow OK. That wasn't clear from the question at all; could you add that in? Anyway, I can't think of a way in plain CSS to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: No, you can not. However, there could be some workaround for your specific case. We can try if you post it.

Comment: @vals https://jsfiddle.net/dxng3xm8/8/ here

Answer (score 3):

A little bit tricky, but here we go.

I am using an inline style to make the elements position themselves, then a single transform arranges them all:

```css
.container,
.elem {
  transform-style: preserve-3D;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.elem {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transform-origin: 235px center;
}

body:hover .container {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

body:hover .elem {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
  <div class="elem"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: this is an interesting approach, I was thinking on going this route too